# Return a value, even when a sub-query in a where returns empty set

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

I have a query that is a little like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MyColumn, "Not Applicable") As MyColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeOtherColumn =
(SELECT AValue
FROM SomeOtherTable
WHERE SomeConditionHolds
)
```

If the relevant value for MyColumn has a value, I get this, and if it is null, this gives me "Not Applicable" as desired.

However, occasionally the sub-query returns empty set, in which case the whole query returns empty set also.  I would still like it to return "Not applicable."

The best I have been able to do is add to the above

```
UNION
SELECT 'Not Applicable' AS MyColumn
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT AValue
FROM SomeOtherTable
WHERE SomeConditionHolds
)
```

But this feels really hacky and inefficient.  I hope someone has a better idea.

Comment: You can run the first select with the results going to a temporary table or table variable, then check `@@RowCount`.  If it is zero then return your N/A row, otherwise return the temporary results.

Comment: This has been stagnant for a while, and the problem above was merely one step in a larger problem, and I found a completely different solution to that.  However, along the way I did experiment with the two types of joins mentioned by the answers and all still return emtpy set when the sub-query portion returns empty set.  So I don't feel I can accept any answers.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(MyColumn, DummyCol) As MyColumn
FROM MyTable 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 'Not Available' AS DummyCol) Q ON DummyCol IS NOT NULL
   AND SomeOtherColumn =
     (SELECT AValue
     FROM SomeOtherTable
     WHERE SomeConditionHolds
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    SELECT Case When T.AValue Is Null Then 'Not Applicable' Else MyColumn End As MyColumn
    FROM MyTable Left Outer Join 
   (SELECT AValue
    FROM SomeOtherTable
    WHERE SomeConditionHolds
   ) T on MyTable.SomeOtherColumn  = T.AValue
```

Comment: no different exist , when result is null no row exist and ISNULL not applicable and your query result may be all  Rows !!!(left join return all left table rows without right table condition)

Comment: But i think it is not necessary.

Comment: @BehrouzBakhtiari, if you use LEFT JOIN, does it return all record all the time, even there are match records.

Comment: @BehrouzBakhtiari, this is not going to work - the OP needs to return only rows for which MyTable.SomeOtherColumn equals the AValue from the sub query, or a dummy "NOT AVAIALBLE" when the actual return result is empty. Your query will return the entire MyTable - you don't have a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

get Query result and when no Row exist set result with "Not Applicable"  otherwise you must double check and waste system time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your subquery returns one value, you can easily convert this to an outer join, which will always give you a row and which will also make the query more efficient and elegant:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(MyColumn, "Not Applicable") As MyColumn
FROM MyTable
LEFT JOIN SomeOtherTable
    ON SomeOtherColumn = AValue
    AND SomeConditionHolds
```

The key thing here is that `SomeConditionHolds` is in the *join* condition, *not* the where clause, otherwise the left join effectively becomes an inner join.

Comment: I think OP asks for a solution when MyTable returns NO rows. In which case your LEFT JOIN will come back empty.

Comment: @G.Stoynev no - it's the *joined* table (from the subquery) that may have no row. The OP says **However, occasionally the sub-query returns empty set, in which case the whole query returns empty set also.**. This query addresses that problem, perfectly IMHO.

Comment: Well, his main predicate is `WHERE SomeOtherColumn = <something>`. The subquery NOT returning a value means that his main predicate returns false, which in turn means his MyTable *should* return no rows. And I feel he confirms that my interpretation with the way he did the UNION.

Comment: From the OP's query, it is apparent that `MyColumn` comes from `MyTable`. You are putting `MyTable` on the left side of a left join, meaning `MyTable` will *always* return rows (provided it's got any, of course), meaning in turn that `MyColumn` will *never* be NULL (unless it is nullable and the NULL comes as the column's own contents).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Foo as Table ( FooId Int Identity, Something VarChar(16) );
insert into @Foo ( Something ) values
  ( 'One' ), ( 'II' ), ( '3' );

declare @FooLimit as Int = 1; -- Try 5.

with Alicia as (
  select FooId, Something, 1 as SetId
    from @Foo
    where FooId >= @FooLimit
  union all
  select 42, 'n/a', 2 )
  select FooId, Something
    from Alicia
    where SetId = ( select Min( SetId ) from Alicia )
```